# Determin email provider url by the email iteslf

Tags: php, email, service

We would like to do a redirect of a user to his email provider after registration. The question is - how do we find where to redirect?

Is there a tool or API for that?

Comment: What do you mean? Redirect the user to `google.com/gmail`if he/she uses a domain like `gmail.com`?

Comment: @ojovirtual, yes, exactly.

Comment: Don't know any service for that. You could do a database of the main service providers and if the users belongs to one of them, redirect him there. This will work for the most of the people. In addition, you can, based on the domain of the email account, check the `MX` record on the `DNS` server for this domain and use it to check the provider.

Comment: Well, that is an option indeed, but you can't really automate that - will have to go manually over the emails (as much as we have in db and we can imagine). But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found anything useful so far and there are no new answers for a while, decided to compile a script based on @ojovirtual's comment.

The idea remains the same - fetch the `MX` record and map it to service `URL`:

```
<?php

function getMailServiceUrl($email) 
{
    getmxrr(array_pop(explode('@', $email)), $mx);

    $servicesMap = [
        // MX record => service URL
        'mx15.ukraine.com.ua' => 'https://webmail.adm.tools',
        'alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com' => 'https://gmail.com',
        'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com' => 'https://gmail.com'
    ];

    foreach ($mx as $key => $name) {
        if (isset($servicesMap[$name])) {
            return $servicesMap[$name];
        }
    }

    throw new \LogicException('Not found');
}
```

Hope that helps someone.